# "How to fix the error table already exists in sql in a python IDE using CREATE method?"

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

The error keeps popping out when I used `Pycharm`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aaa/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/sql_class.py", line 11, in <module>
    cur.execute(customers_sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table customers already exists
```

I am using `Pycharm` importing  `sqlite3`

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('data_info.sqlite3')
# 'connect' is similar to 'open' in a text file
cur = con.cursor()
# instantiate a cursor obj
customers_sql = """
      CREATE TABLE customers (
      id integer PRIMARY KEY,
      first_name text NOT NULL,
      last_name text NOT NULL)"""
cur.execute(customers_sql)


products_sql = """
      CREATE TABLE products (
      id integer PRIMARY KEY,
      name text NOT NULL,
      price real NOT NULL)"""
cur.execute(products_sql)


orders_sql = """
    CREATE TABLE orders (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    date text NOT NULL,
    customer_id integer ,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id) )
    """
cur.execute(orders_sql)

lineitems_sql = """
    CREATE TABLE lineitems (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    quantity integer NOT NULL,
    total real NOT NULL,
    product_id integer,
    order_id integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order (id) )"""
cur.execute(lineitems_sql)

#1st method of inputting
products_sql = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES ('introduction 
to combinatorics', 6.89)"
cur.execute(products_sql)

#2nd method
products_sql = "INSERT INTO produts (name, price) VALUES(?, ?)"
cur.execute(products_sql,
            ('introduction to combinatorics', 7.99))
cur.execute(products_sql,
            ('introduction to combinatorics', 8.44))
# SELECTING OR EXTRACTING FROM A TABLE WITH DATA
cur.execute("SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id =1")
result = cur.fetchone()
# fetchone is for picking just one
print(result)
```

The expected output is to print out the table.

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to create a table that already exists, which is not possible in Sqlite.

To solve this, you can use the [IF NOT EXISTS](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-table/) statement on your queries.

So your code block would be:

```
customers_sql = """
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (
      id integer PRIMARY KEY,
      first_name text NOT NULL,
      last_name text NOT NULL)"""
```

Comment: I was told by someone that long sql codes does not work with pycharm